# Is there a way to broadcast to all clients except sender in python?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, distributed-system

guys. 
I need to implement an algorithm: Leader Election in a Static Network, but 
I'm not able to send a message to all nodes except the sender. Any help?

Comment: You may broadcast message to all clients and while processing request ignore request whose incoming node is same as itself.

Comment: i get it, thank you so much.